# How to Bring the Scene View Camera Controls into Game View

Tags: unity, camera, scene, control, view

I've got a scene with a big sphere in the centre (the Earth) and a lot of smaller spheres around (the stars).

[image: Scene View]

Above is a screengrab in Scene View with the camera in the Front View position.

I really like the controls in Unity's Scene View when moving around the viewport and I was wondering whether it can be brought into the Game View.

How can I do this?

Comment: Write an Update script that listens for keyboard/mouse input and moves the camera based on that input. You can implement any control scheme you want that way, including the style used by the Unity scene view controls. How have you tried implementing this so far? What specific step of the process do you need help with?

Comment: There is a asset in unity Assets store with similar functionality https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/slug/206392?_ga=2.80718293.374278615.1641009246-1107228148.1628395728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know what? I will be generous. Here is a a script made by unity that pretty much does this for you. Enjoy.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityEngine.Rendering
{
    [HelpURL(Documentation.baseURL + Documentation.version + Documentation.subURL + "Free-Camera" + Documentation.endURL)]
    [ExecuteAlways]
    public class FreeCamera : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float m_LookSpeedController = 120f;
        public float m_LookSpeedMouse = 10.0f;
        public float m_MoveSpeed = 10.0f;
        public float m_MoveSpeedIncrement = 2.5f;
        public float m_Turbo = 10.0f;

        private static string kMouseX = "Mouse X";
        private static string kMouseY = "Mouse Y";
        private static string kRightStickX = "Controller Right Stick X";
        private static string kRightStickY = "Controller Right Stick Y";
        private static string kVertical = "Vertical";
        private static string kHorizontal = "Horizontal";

        private static string kYAxis = "YAxis";
        private static string kSpeedAxis = "Speed Axis";

        void OnEnable()
        {
            RegisterInputs();
        }

        void RegisterInputs()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            List<InputManagerEntry> inputEntries = new List<InputManagerEntry>();

            // Add new bindings
            inputEntries.Add(new InputManagerEntry { name = kRightStickX, kind = InputManagerEntry.Kind.Axis, axis = InputManagerEntry.Axis.Fourth, sensitivity = 1.0f, gravity = 1.0f, deadZone = 0.2f });
            inputEntries.Add(new InputManagerEntry { name = kRightStickY, kind = InputManagerEntry.Kind.Axis, axis = InputManagerEntry.Axis.Fifth, sensitivity = 1.0f, gravity = 1.0f, deadZone = 0.2f, invert = true });

            inputEntries.Add(new InputManagerEntry { name = kYAxis, kind = InputManagerEntry.Kind.KeyOrButton, btnPositive = "page up", altBtnPositive = "joystick button 5", btnNegative = "page down", altBtnNegative = "joystick button 4", gravity = 1000.0f, deadZone = 0.001f, sensitivity = 1000.0f });

            inputEntries.Add(new InputManagerEntry { name = kSpeedAxis, kind = InputManagerEntry.Kind.KeyOrButton, btnPositive = "home", btnNegative = "end", gravity = 1000.0f, deadZone = 0.001f, sensitivity = 1000.0f });
            inputEntries.Add(new InputManagerEntry { name = kSpeedAxis, kind = InputManagerEntry.Kind.Axis, axis = InputManagerEntry.Axis.Seventh, gravity = 1000.0f, deadZone = 0.001f, sensitivity = 1000.0f });

            InputRegistering.RegisterInputs(inputEntries);
#endif
        }

        void Update()
        {
            // If the debug menu is running, we don't want to conflict with its inputs.
            if (DebugManager.instance.displayRuntimeUI)
                return;

            float inputRotateAxisX = 0.0f;
            float inputRotateAxisY = 0.0f;
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                inputRotateAxisX = Input.GetAxis(kMouseX) * m_LookSpeedMouse;
                inputRotateAxisY = Input.GetAxis(kMouseY) * m_LookSpeedMouse;
            }
            inputRotateAxisX += (Input.GetAxis(kRightStickX) * m_LookSpeedController * Time.deltaTime);
            inputRotateAxisY += (Input.GetAxis(kRightStickY) * m_LookSpeedController * Time.deltaTime);

            float inputChangeSpeed = Input.GetAxis(kSpeedAxis);
            if (inputChangeSpeed != 0.0f)
            {
                m_MoveSpeed += inputChangeSpeed * m_MoveSpeedIncrement;
                if (m_MoveSpeed < m_MoveSpeedIncrement) m_MoveSpeed = m_MoveSpeedIncrement;
            }

            float inputVertical = Input.GetAxis(kVertical);
            float inputHorizontal = Input.GetAxis(kHorizontal);
            float inputYAxis = Input.GetAxis(kYAxis);

            bool moved = inputRotateAxisX != 0.0f || inputRotateAxisY != 0.0f || inputVertical != 0.0f || inputHorizontal != 0.0f || inputYAxis != 0.0f;
            if (moved)
            {
                float rotationX = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
                float newRotationY = transform.localEulerAngles.y + inputRotateAxisX;

                // Weird clamping code due to weird Euler angle mapping...
                float newRotationX = (rotationX - inputRotateAxisY);
                if (rotationX <= 90.0f && newRotationX >= 0.0f)
                    newRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(newRotationX, 0.0f, 90.0f);
                if (rotationX >= 270.0f)
                    newRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(newRotationX, 270.0f, 360.0f);

                transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRotationX, newRotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.z);

                float moveSpeed = Time.deltaTime * m_MoveSpeed;
                if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
                    moveSpeed *= Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? m_Turbo : 1.0f;
                else
                    moveSpeed *= Input.GetAxis("Fire1") > 0.0f ? m_Turbo : 1.0f;
                transform.position += transform.forward * moveSpeed * inputVertical;
                transform.position += transform.right * moveSpeed * inputHorizontal;
                transform.position += Vector3.up * moveSpeed * inputYAxis;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am getting a few errors, DebugManager, Documentation, InputManagerEntry and InputRegistering doesn't seem to exist. And the namespace InputManagerEntry couldn't be found. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Well this script is part of the core RP library. I suppose your Unity version is older or you actually need the package that this come from which is Core RP.https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core@7.1/manual/Free-Camera.html